# QF_NIA script terminates instantly with Z3 4.3.2, but not with 4.4.2

Tags: z3

This [script](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/TkAL) produces a correct model in almost no time with Z3 4.3.2, but runs seemingly forever with Z3 4.4.2 and timeouts after a few seconds on Rise4fun.  A version of the script for `n=5` (the one linked has `n=4`) runs for a long time also on 4.3.2.  I tried changing `sat.random_seed` and `smt.random_seed`, but to no avail.  What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the example. The bit-blaster now detects that this is finite domain. It was not handling "distinct" so therefore falling back to the default solver that uses a super-expensive Groebner bases computation. It can be turned off, but better to fix the finite domain detection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix!  Building from github, however, produces a Z3 that complains about a double free if `get-model` is asked to report the values of the `x_i`s and `y_i`s.